# ASP.NET Applications WMI class not found

Tags: asp.net, performance-monitoring, wmi

I'm trying to instrument ASP.NET cache behavior on a web cluster by accessing the counters in the WMI class, Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications. 2 of my servers have this class, but 1 does not.  They all have the versioned class (Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319), but not the general.

How can I get WMI to expose the Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications class.  It is visible in perfmon.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the WMI counters did the trick. (logicmonitor support provided this)

```
REBUILDING WMI COUNTERS

cd c:\windows\system32
lodctr /R
cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
lodctr /R
Resyncing the counters with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI):
WINMGMT.EXE /RESYNCPERF
Stop and restart the Performance Logs and Alerts service.
Stop and restart the Windows Management Instrumentation service.
```